# No region found within the locale 'shi'

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, locale

While opening `Sales->Order` Grid in magento backend, i am getting this issue -

```
No region found within the locale 'shi'
```

I have searched for the solution but nothing to work for my case. If anyone have the idea to resolve that would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
a:5:{i:0;s:39:"No region found within the locale 'shi'";i:1;s:5148:"#0 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/lib/Zend/Currency.php(103): Zend_Currency->setLocale('shi')
#1 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(614): Zend_Currency->__construct('shi')
#2 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Currency.php(63): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->currency('shi')
#3 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php(128): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Currency->render(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#4 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml(161): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getRowField(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#5 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/vulgarci/...')
#6 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#7 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#12 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#13 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#14 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/vulgarci/...')
#15 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#20 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#22 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#24 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#25 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/vulgarci/...')
#26 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#27 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#32 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#33 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#34 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#35 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 /home/vulgarci/public_html/vc/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#39 {main}";s:3:"url";s:75:"/vc/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/087ad6c12b1cd570b8518e888b7bbf01/";s:11:"script_name";s:13:"/vc/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also this exact problem with currency 'Eur'.

It is in a test environment.

Probably went something wrong with my last test order.

When I removed this order (with a php program) this problem was solved.

Edit:

My problem was with orders and payment methods (now both solved) that my upgrade from 1.5 to 1.9 went right except for the valuta settings in admin (no 'Euro' but Afghan..), another time I have done this upgrade (still testing) I did not have this problem, yes that is Magento, it takes all your time .. up to the next errors ..

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the wrong currency was added to the order. Im not sure exactly how the currency was added or if its done through a third party module / programatically.

To see this, check the table `sales_flat_order_grid` and check the columns **base_currency_code** and the **order_currency_code**. Assuming the locale "shi" is currency "Moroccan Dirham", then one or both of the columns should have the value **MAD** instead of **shi**. The same will apply to the `sales_flat_order` table.

I ran a simple test:

Test 1: (Failed)

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$c = new Zend_Currency;

$c->setLocale('shi');

Mage::log($c);
```

Output:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Currency_Exception' with message 'No region found within the locale 'shi''
```

Test 2: (Successful)

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$c = new Zend_Currency;

$c->setLocale('shi_Tfng_MA');

Mage::log($c);
```

Output:

```
2015-05-10T11:12:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): Zend_Currency Object
(
    [_options:protected] => Array
        (
            [position] => 8
            [script] => 
            [format] => 
            [display] => 2
            [precision] => 2
            [name] => adrim n lmɣrib
            [currency] => MAD
            [symbol] => 
            [locale] => shi_MA
            [value] => 0
            [service] => 
            [tag] => Zend_Locale
        )

)
```

So in short, make sure the correct locale is set to **shi_MA** and the currencies in the table are set to **MAD**